# How would I create a proof In SL

Tags: logic, proof

```
H
Therefore,
S ⇒(B ⇒H)
```

How would I create a proof in SL which shows the following argument is valid in SL.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You might get more answers if you provide some extra context, share your thoughts and efforts to do the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SL is Sentential Logic and you may use a version of Natural Deduction rules.

You have a nested conditional sentence, which indicated that you should nest Conditional Proofs (CP).

Look to Rules for "→" and in particular the rule of →I (conditional introduction).